# Dockerfile to download Java 8 on Amazon Beanstalk Linux

Tags: java, linux, amazon-web-services, playframework, java-8

Trying to create a Dockerfile that'll download and install Java 8 on Amazon Linux.

Currently, I have the following file. It's a Play 2.3.4 app:

```
FROM dockerfile/java

RUN \
  echo oracle-java8-installer shared/accepted-oracle-license-v1-1 select true | debconf-set-selections && \
  add-apt-repository -y ppa:webupd8team/java && \
  apt-get update && \
  apt-get install -y oracle-java8-installer && \
  rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

MAINTAINER BeanstalkTest
EXPOSE 80 443
ADD files /
WORKDIR /opt/docker
RUN ["chown", "-R", "daemon", "."]
USER daemon
RUN ["bin/playapp", "-Dconfig.file=conf/prod.conf"]
```

The app takes a long time to deploy then fails. Any ideas what I could be doing wrong?

Comment: Not a solution, but here’s a workaround: [Azul Systems](http://www.azulsystems.com) just announced and shipped a build of OpenJDK for both Java 6 & 7 & 8 including support for Docker. This free and open-source product is called [Zulu](http://www.azulsystems.com/products/zulu). They offer [commercial support](http://www.azulsystems.com/products/zulu/support-packages) as well. To quote: `The only commercialized multi-platform build of OpenJDK: Free, 100% open source Java for Windows, Linux (including Docker), Mac OS X and the Cloud`. I've not used it yet, but it sparked my interest in Docker.

Answer (score 0):

For me it looks like problem with connection.

1. Are you sure that this code works without Docker inside target host?
2. Does it work in your machine?
3. Are you sure that `echo` command is doing what you really want ? I mean installing java 8.

Ok so I will post my ideas:

- Set up proxies: `HTTP_PROXY, http_proxy, HTTPS_PROXY, https_proxy, http-proxy, https-proxy` - yes that many proxies because different packages use different names of proxy.
- Add proxy to `etc/apt/apt.conf` to `Acquire::http::Proxy "http://proxy-abc.com:888/";`
- Add proxy to docker:

Inside `etc/default/docker`:

```
export http_proxy=http://proxy-abc.com:888/
export https_proxy=https://proxy-abc.com:888/
DOCKER_OPTS="-H tcp://127.0.0.1:4243 -H unix://var/run/docker.sock -g /docker"
```

- Look at docker container logs: `sudo cat log/var/lib/docker/containers/12eaca16d3cdc628304263b21d27614e5a0c44f09c2072470b09a1bb3def5559/12eaca16d3cdc628304263b21d27614e5a0c44f09c2072470b09a1bb3def5559-json.log`
- Does your target host has newest kernel ? In older kernels docker had problems with network communication
- Does your target host had newest docker installed?

**EDIT**

Why wouldn't use prebuild images? `FROM dockerfile/java:oracle-java8`